# XML child item search with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have the below xml format and have the id's in text file format. I need to use the powershell to accomplish this. I am not able to correctly search in the child items

No.'s Text File

```
121
120
133
```

XML File Format:

```
<All>
  <section1 name= "mysec1">
    <id category="Roll" no="121" sub="Eng" />
    <id category="nam" no="123" sub="Geo" />
    <id category="Roll" no="120" sub="Bot" />
</section1>
  <section1 name= "mysec2">
    <id category="Roll" no="141" sub="Sci" />
    <id category="nam" no="133" sub="Geo" />
    <id category="Roll" no="150" sub="Bot" />
</section1>
</All>
```

Need to search in the xml file according to Nos. 
 So  output will be

```
121: Roll_mysec1_Eng
120: Roll_mysec1_Bot
133: nam_mysec2_Geo
```

Comment: This isn't valid xml, is it? `<section1 = "mysec1">`?

Comment: Updated the xml format.. this is a sample xml so missed the tag there

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter the nodes based on the text file content to find the nodes you want.

```
$foundIds = $xml.all.section1.id | Where { $textFile -contains $_.no }
```

Then, to get the output format you're expecting, again, just format it as you want it:

```
$foundIds | Foreach { "$($_.no): $($_.category)_$($_.parentnode.name)_$($_.sub)" }
```

Here's a full sample, using your sample data and with replacement lines for getting the data from files instead (you could potentially want to add an `-Encoding` parameter to the `Get-Content` calls).

```
$textFile = @"
121
120
133
"@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

[xml]$xml = @"
<All>
  <section1 name="mysec1">
    <id category="Roll" no="121" sub="Eng" />
    <id category="nam" no="123" sub="Geo" />
    <id category="Roll" no="120" sub="Bot" />
</section1>
  <section1 name="mysec2">
    <id category="Roll" no="141" sub="Sci" />
    <id category="nam" no="133" sub="Geo" />
    <id category="Roll" no="150" sub="Bot" />
</section1>
</All>
"@

#When you have this data in files, you should replace the scripb above
#with the following two lines instead
#$textFile = Get-Content C:\textfile.txt
#[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\data.xml

$foundIds = $xml.all.section1.id | Where { $textFile -contains $_.no }

$foundIds | Foreach { "$($_.no): $($_.category)_$($_.parentnode.name)_$($_.sub)" }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cat ids.txt | % { 
  Select-Xml -Path xml.xml -XPath "//id[@no=$_]" 
  } | % { 
     $_.node 
     } | % { 
      "{0}: {1}_{2}_{3}" -f $_.no,$_.category,$( $_.parentnode | select -expand name ),$_.sub 
      }
```